# Flutter Amplify: How to get user id after signup

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I am recently using Amplify library for my Flutter project to use Cognito service in AWS. I want to signup a user and get the user id in Cognito so that I can save it in my own database. I have some other attributes for the user which may not be suitable to put in Cognito database.

Currently I confirm user's email by sending them a link rather than a verification code so that the user only need to click the link in email, rather copying verification code over.

I have the following sample code to illustrate my purpose

```
Future<void> signUp(String username, String password, String email) async {
    try {
      SignUpResult result = await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
          username: username, password: password, options: CognitoSignUpOptions(userAttributes: {'email': email}));
      //String userId = await Amplify.Auth.SomeFunction();
      //Save userId to my own database
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Currently, the sign up result is

[image]

In this article https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-up, it says with js, we can get the CognitoUser after signing up. But could not find equivalent feature for Flutter.

Can anyone please give some advice? Thank you

Comment: What do you have in the response?

Comment: Hi @stacktrace2234, I have attached an image to show what I have in the response of sign up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `getCurrentUser` Method from the [Auth package](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/#option-1-use-authenticator-ui-library). This will give you the [AuthUser](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/blob/1959ea13fb6287a544987021e5225576059e10d6/packages/amplify_auth_plugin_interface/lib/src/Session/AuthUser.dart) which is a object with two string properties (userId & username) which you can use further more, if you need them.

So for exactly this problem it would mean:

```
Future<void> signUp(String username, String password, String email) async {
try {
  SignUpResult result = await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
      username: username, password: password, options: CognitoSignUpOptions(userAttributes: {'email': email}));
      final user = await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser(); //This will give you the AuthUser 
      //Mock for save userId to my own database
      databaseService.saveUserIdToDatabase(user.userId);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you maybe add an example code snippet to the answer?

Comment: @Rick Rackow, I updated my answer with the relevant example to get the current User

Comment: getCurrentUser() doesn't give you AuthUser unless user is signedIn. Right after signup getCurrentUser() will show SignedOutException