# How can I access UserAttributes from Amplify

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I want to return the user ID of my user attributes in aws Amplify Cognito. I can print all attributes but unfortunately, I can't use the == operator. The code sample from aws works for me. https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/user-attributes/q/platform/flutter/#fetch-the-current-users-attributes

```
 Future<void> fetchCurrentUserAttributes() async {
  try {
    final result = await Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes();
    for (final element in result) {
      print('key: ${element.userAttributeKey}; value: ${element.value}');
    }
  } on AuthException catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }
}
```

This is my print:

Print of the aws code

[image: 1]

But now I want to access the id with the key 'sub'.
I'm working with the sample from Kilo-Loco https://github.com/Kilo-Loco/30DaysOfFlutter/blob/main/day23_user_authentication/lib/auth/auth_repository.dart

```
  Future<String> _getUserIdFromAttributes() async {
    try {
      final attributes = await Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes();
      final userId = attributes
          .firstWhere((element) => element.userAttributeKey  == "sub")
          .value;
      debugPrint('User ID: ');
      debugPrint(userId);
      return userId;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

The warning Message I'm getting is: Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types.

.runtimeType says it is a string.
So when I run the Code it always stores the value null in userId.
Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I may be a bit late but I've stumbled upon the same issue. The issue you have is that

```
element.userAttributeKey
```

is not of type `String` but `UserAttributeKey`. You have to compare `"sub"` to the actual key string like the following.

```
final userId = attributes
  .firstWhere((element) => element.userAttributeKey.key  == "sub")
  .value;
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you LucienZ for your help! Just tried it out and it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve that specific problem but I found this way to access the userId which is working well for me. [Flutter Amplify: How to get user id after signup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032336/flutter-amplify-how-to-get-user-id-after-signup?rq=1)

```
  Future<String> _getUserIdFromAttributes() async {
    try {
      final user = await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();
      final userident = user.userId;
      debugPrint('User ID:  ');
      debugPrint(userident);
      return userident;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```